# How to filter result by a specific value on one field OR a list of values on another field

Tags: c#, linq

**GOAL:** I have a Cosmos DB and I want to load objects that are filtered either by a specific value on one field, the `UserId` (`string`), OR by checking if the value of another field (inside a custom class), the `TypeId` (`Guid`), exists in the list of `Role.TypeId`. The objects are taken from the database in the form of `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`.

**CURRENT STATUS:** I am trying to run one of the following commands:

```
var query = documentClient
                .CreateDocumentQuery<Dictionary<string, object>>(objectCollectionUri, option)
                .Where(p => (string) p["UserId"] == (string) user.UserId 
                            || user.Role.Any(role => role.TypeId == Guid.Parse(p["TypeId"].ToString())));
            var count = query.Count(p => (DateTime)p["LastModified"] >= now);
```

or

```
var query = documentClient
                .CreateDocumentQuery<Dictionary<string, object>>(objectCollectionUri, option)
                .Where(p => (string) p["UserId"] == (string) user.UserId 
                            || user.Role.Any(role => role.TypeId == Guid.Parse(p["TypeId"].ToString()))).AsEnumerable();
            var count = query.Count(p => (DateTime)p["LastModified"] >= now);
```

It is not working with either `IQueryable` (first) nor `IEnumerable` (second).

**PROBLEM:** In all variations I am getting the following error:

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Input is not of type IDocumentQuery., Windows/10.0.17763 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.10.3)
---- Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryException : Input is not of type IDocumentQuery., Windows/10.0.17763 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.10.3
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at LF.AzureFunction.Tests.TestBaseLoad.TestNonAdminRoleAccessByLastModified() in C:\Users\Spyridon\source\repos\logicflow-base\src\LF.AzureFunction.Tests\TestBaseLoad.cs:line 161
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.TranslateInput(ConstantExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.Translate(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.Translate(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitCollectionExpression(Expression expression, TranslationContext context, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitCollectionExpression(Expression expression, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.CreateSubquery(Expression expression, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression expression, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression expression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitNonSubqueryScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitNonSubqueryScalarExpression(Expression expression, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression expression, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(LambdaExpression lambda, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitWhere(ReadOnlyCollection`1 arguments, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.Translate(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.Translate(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.SqlTranslator.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.HandleMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.Evaluate(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.get_QuerySpec()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextFactory.CreateDocumentQueryExecutionContextAsync(IDocumentQueryClient client, ResourceType resourceTypeEnum, Type resourceType, Expression expression, FeedOptions feedOptions, String resourceLink, Boolean isContinuationExpected, CancellationToken token, Guid correlatedActivityId)
```

**QUESTION:** How can I achieve the following query in LINQ?

```
SELECT COUNT(something)
FROM somewhere
WHERE field1 = value1 OR
   field2 in SET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Contains` instead of `Any`:

```
var roleTypeIds = user.Role.Select(r => r.TypeId.ToString()).ToList(); // maybe will need to play with format for ToString
var query = ...
 .Where(p => (string) p["UserId"] == (string) user.UserId 
    || roleTypeIds.Contains((string)p["TypeId"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem is in that part `p["TypeId"].Equals(user.Role.Any())` of your query. You may need to change it to `user.Role.Any(r => r == p["TypeId"])`.

The query provider used here seems not to be supporting `object.Equals`.